# Call Super-Constructor multiple times

Tags: java, inheritance, extends, super

In my current programming project I have some basic classes, like Numbers or ImageSets. In other classes I use these to display Information. I thought the easiest way (not so much coding) is to let the Display-Classes extend the base-Classes.

But at one Class (TwoDigits) I need two instances of the superclass (ImageSet). Is this possible? Normally you would call super(), but a second super() call is not allowed...

Here is some code of the Number-Class: (Element is another abstract selfmade class)

```java
public class ImageSet extends Element{

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int imageIndex;
    private int imagesCount;

    public ImageSet(int x,int y,int imageIndex,int imagesCount, boolean ignoreDimension) throws IOException, UnequalDimensionsException {
        if(!ignoreDimension) {
            [...]//Check for equal Dimensions, otherwise throw UnequalDimensionsException
        }

        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.imageIndex=imageIndex;
        this.imagesCount=imagesCount;
    }

[...]

}
```

Here is some code from the Base-Class (TwoDigits):

```java
public class TwoDigits extends Element{

    ImageSet tens;
    ImageSet ones;
    Dimension d = null;

    public TwoDigits(int x, int y, int imageIndex, int imageCount, boolean ignoreDimension) throws UnequalDimensionsException, IOException{
        tens = new ImageSet(x,y,imageIndex,imageCount,ignoreDimension);
        String imageIndexFormatted = String.format("%04d", imageIndex);
        d = StaticHelpers.getImageDimension(new File("data/"+imageIndexFormatted+".png"));
        ones = new ImageSet(x+d.width,y,imageIndex,imageCount,ignoreDimension);
    }

[...]
}
```

I would like to change the SuperClass of TwoDigits to ImageSet to save some code in other classes.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't completely understand your code, but it sounds like a case for composition instead of inheritance. Your TwoDigits could contain two instances of Number. And if you want to also have it extend from Number to share some common code/interface, then maybe you should split Digit (of which you need two instances) from Number (which defines the numbery methods that both Digit and TwoDigits can implement). Finally, are you going to also need ThreeDigits and FourDigits? If so, maybe these should not get separate classes but something based on a List of Digits.

Comment: What is the relationship between `Dimension` and `ImageSet` to `Number`? Shouldn't `Number` also make use of those?

Comment: I confused Number and ImageSet, sorry for that. I meant that I wanted TwoDigits to inherit from ImageSet.

So by that, TwoDigits does contain two instances of ImageSet, but I wanted to change that. ThreeDigits and FourDigits are never needed, only TwoDigits.

Comment: If you need 2 instances of `Number` from a class `TwoDigits`, then you need to use *composition*, not *inheritance*, i.e. your `TwoDigits` class needs 2 fields of type `Number`.

Comment: *contain* is very different from *extend*

Comment: Actually you can use classic object manipulation to achieve that instead of inheritence

Comment: So it would be a better way to let TwoDigits contain two ImageSets? In other classes I need to modify the ImageSets, then I have to pass every method on? Or is there another even better way?

Comment: So if I don't want to modify the ImageSets apart from each other, the only difference is that the x of the second ImageSet is higher than that from the first ImageSet.

Comment: @MonsterDruide1 try to use "@name" to mention someone you are directing your comment

Comment: @Andreas So there is no way to use Inheritance for that?

Comment: No, Java is *single* inheritance. Even in languages supporting multiple inheritance, it's mostly multiple *different* base classes, not two of the same.